# Outer Join Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I am trying to outer join (on df1) two pandas dataframe. Below are the sample data frames:

```
df1:
Index   Team 1   Team 2   Team1_Score    Team2_Score
 0       A        B        25              56
 1       B        C        30              55
 2       D        E        35              75

df2:
Index   Team 1   Team 2   Team1_Avg     Team2_Avg
 0       A        B        5              15
 1       G        F        10             25
 2       C        B        15             35

dfcombined
Index   Team 1   Team 2   Team1_Score    Team2_Score    Team2_Avg     Team1_Avg
 0       A        B        25              56           5             15
 1       B        C        30              55           35            15
 2       D        E        35              75
```

I was trying to use the pandasql module however I am not sure how to handle the case of joining index 1 in df1 and index 2 at df2 as the order of teams is reversed. Through pandasql module, I am not sure how to switch the Team Avg values in the combined data frame if the order of team is reverse.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: would using [`pandas.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) fit your needs? You can also look at `pandas.merge()`

Comment: Take a look at [Database-style DataFrame joining/merging](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) from the `pandas` documentation. For a left outer join, you would want something like `pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', keys=['Team 1', 'Team 2'])`

Comment: Both, an outer merge is not the issue here. The problem is that the order of teams can be different, but the merge but be independent of ordering (that's not as easy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup -

```
df1

      Team 1 Team 2  Team1_Score  Team2_Score
Index                                        
0          A      B           25           56
1          B      C           30           55
2          D      E           35           75

df2

      Team 1 Team 2  Team1_Avg  Team2_Avg
Index                                    
0          A      B          5         15
1          F      G         25         10
2          B      C         35         15
```

First, we'll need to sort the `Team *` columns, and accordingly sort the `Team*_Score` columns in the same way. We'll use `argsort` to do so.

```
i = np.arange(len(df1))[:, None]
j = np.argsort(df1[['Team 1', 'Team 2']], axis=1).values

df1[['Team 1', 'Team 2']] = df1[['Team 1', 'Team 2']].values[i, j]
df1[['Team1_Score', 'Team2_Score']] = df1[['Team1_Score', 'Team2_Score']].values[i, j]
```

Now, repeat the same process for `df2`, with `Team *` and `Team*_Avg`.

```
j = np.argsort(df2[['Team 1', 'Team 2']], axis=1).values

df2[['Team 1', 'Team 2']] = df2[['Team 1', 'Team 2']].values[i, j]
df2[['Team1_Avg', 'Team2_Avg']] = df2[['Team1_Avg', 'Team2_Avg']].values[i, j]
```

Now, perform a left outer `merge` -

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['Team 1', 'Team 2'], how='left')

  Team 1 Team 2  Team1_Score  Team2_Score Team1_Avg Team2_Avg
0      A      B           25           56         5        15
1      B      C           30           55        35        15
2      D      E           35           75
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is duplicate df2 with `pd.concat()` by flipping the column names. You can do this by setting them with `rename`

```
df3 = df2.rename(columns={'Team 1':'Team 2','Team 2':'Team 1', 
        'Team1_Avg':'Team2_Avg','Team2_Avg':'Team1_Avg'})
```

Now we can do a left `merge` and `concat` on both df2 and the newly created `df3`

```
df1.merge(pd.concat([df2,df3]),how='left',on=['Team 1','Team 2'])
```

Which gives you your desired DataFrame

```
  Team 1 Team 2  Team1_Score  Team2_score  Team1_Avg  Team2_Avg
0      A      B           25           56        5.0       15.0
1      B      C           30           55       35.0       15.0
2      D      E           25           75        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: No way, this is something you should not be doing. How can you expect this renaming to work for OP's dataset in general, even if it _does_ work for this dataset by coincidence?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, how is this coincidental, I have used this logic on sport data with no issue

Comment: I'm trying to say you can't reliably rename columns like this, because the sort order could be anything.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, in terms of columns? I dont have an issue doing this with the columns in a random order

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed. I will try both these suggestions. However, wanted to check the performance of both of these if my dataframes grow in size over time. As of now, I have only 15 columns and 10,000 rows in each but this could grow to 25 columns and 500,000 rows. Any suggestion how can i mark the corresponding rows in both data frames that have been merged.