# Pandas - Join two Dataframes based on timestamp insert in between dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I've two dataframes with matching and non-matching timestamps. I want to join both the dataframes such that new dataframe contains timestamps from both the dataframes and missing data from other dataframe is set to that dataframe's previous value. I want to analyze two different data sets to check their value at any exact timestamp (moment)

```
DF1
| Data1 |  Timestamp1  |
| ----- |  ----------  |
|   A   | 1623974400000|
|   B   | 1623974400200|
|   C   | 1623974400200|
|   D   | 1623974400400|

DF2
| Data2 |  Timestamp2  |
| ----- |  ----------  |
|   M   | 1623974400000|
|   N   | 1623974400100|
|   O   | 1623974400200|
|   P   | 1623974400500|

Output:
DF3
| Data1 | Data2 |   Timestamp  |
| ----- | ----- |   ---------  |
|   A   |   M   | 1623974400000|
|   A   |   N   | 1623974400100|
|   B   |   O   | 1623974400200|
|   C   |   O   | 1623974400200|
|   D   |   O   | 1623974400400|
|   D   |   P   | 1623974400500|
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outer Join Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981067/outer-join-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: No, it didn't. In that question, data is not preserved if it doesn't exist in the second dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, just `outer merge`. `sort_values` and `fillna forward`.

Code below

Rename columns

```
DF1.rename(columns={'Timestamp1':'Timestamp'}, inplace=True)
DF2.rename(columns={'Timestamp2':'Timestamp'}, inplace=True)
```

merge

```
pd.merge(DF1,DF2, on='Timestamp', how='outer').sort_values(by='Timestamp').fillna(method='ffill')
```

outcome

```
   Data1      Timestamp Data2
0     A  1623974400000     M
4     A  1623974400100     N
1     B  1623974400200     O
2     C  1623974400200     O
3     D  1623974400400     O
5     D  1623974400500     P
```

Comment: It seems to be concise. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas-merge-asof):

```py
# sort dfs by timestamp:
df1 = df1.sort_values(by="Timestamp1")
df2 = df2.sort_values(by="Timestamp2")

x = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on="Timestamp1", right_on="Timestamp2")
y = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, left_on="Timestamp2", right_on="Timestamp1")
df_out = pd.concat([x, y]).drop_duplicates()
df_out["Timestamp"] = df_out[["Timestamp1", "Timestamp2"]].max(axis=1)
print(df_out[["Data1", "Data2", "Timestamp"]])
```

Prints:

```
  Data1 Data2      Timestamp
0     A     M  1623974400000
1     B     O  1623974400200
2     C     O  1623974400200
3     D     O  1623974400400
1     A     N  1623974400100
3     D     P  1623974400500
```